# Parameter confusion in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

I have a question, I have the following factory:

```
angular.module('ospApp')
    .factory('Author', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/authors/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    var birthDateFrom = data.birthDate.split("-");
                    data.birthDate = new Date(new Date(birthDateFrom[0], birthDateFrom[1] - 1, birthDateFrom[2]));
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    });
```

Then I don't see parameter id in query under please tell me:

```
Author.query({page: $scope.page, per_page: 20}, function(result, headers) {
   $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
   $scope.authors = result;
});
```

Comment: You do a query so why would you want to pass an id parameter? What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Query based on id? That is a normal use case.